# LLDB: view real value of the UIModalPresentationStyle enum

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, lldb

While debugging with a breakpoint set for a method of an instance of `UIViewController`, I decided to check  the value of `UIModalPresentationStyle`.

Here's what I got:

```
(lldb) po self.modalPresentationStyle
__C.UIModalPresentationStyle
```

**How can I get the REAL value of the variable, not its type?**

I can "reverse-engineer" it by executing the following command:

```
(lldb) po self.modalPresentationStyle == .fullScreen
false
```

But how can I achieve the desired result faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `po` command asks the object for its description of itself.  I'm not sure why the swift object description of UIModalPresentationStyle just prints its type.  That might be worth a swift bug.

But if you ask lldb to evaluate the expression and return its value for you - rather than presenting that value's object's description - with:

```
(lldb) p self.modalPresentationStyle
(UIModalPresentationStyle) $R0 = fullScreen
```

you sometimes get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

After some experimentation, I can't get LLDB to print the symbolic value from the enum either.   However, there is a kind of halfway option for cases like this:

```
po self.modalPresentationStyle.rawValue
```

You can at least get the numeric value of the position in the enum, and either look at the enum definition or memorize key values to match the number you get out.  For string enums the result would be more clear.